# How to create backup of my directory with password protected zip file in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I want to create a weekly backup of my project directory in PHP. I need help to create a password protected zip file in php. I use the below function, but that not create a whole folder backup as well as not helping for password protected.

```
    $path = realpath('');
    $files = glob($path.'*');
    $files = $files[0];
    $password = "test';
    @system('zip -P $password'.$filename.' '.$files);
```

Comment: Take a look at the **php ZipArchive** class and the function `$zip->setPassword("YourPasswordHere");`

Comment: This function only sets the password to be used to decompress the archive; it does not turn a non-password-protected ZipArchive into a password-protected ZipArchive.

Comment: I recommend you yo read https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35818/are-password-protected-zip-files-secure before using zip and password...

Answer (score 0):

Using zip command you can try the following.

```
<?php 
   $path = realpath('');
   $password = "test";
   $zipFileName = "file.zip";
   exec ("zip -r -P {$password} {$zipFileName} {$path}");
?>
```

`-r` is added to add all the files recursively.

You can use function `system()` or `exec()` to execute the command.

See this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/zip-all-files-in-directory